# CSS Grid with Django

Tags: css, django, css-grid

I am studying Django and I have a question regarding CSS Grids and Dynamic content.

In the HTML code below I am trying to get from my `views.py` file the values of a dictionary.

```
# From 'views.py'

def index(request):
    
    values = {
        1: 'Value 1',
        2: 'Value 2',
        3: 'Value 3'
        }
    
    past_values = {
        'past_values': experiences
        }
```

This is part of the HTML I was talking about:

```
<!-- START PORTFOLIO -->
    <section id="portfolio" class="tm-portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 wow bounce">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h2 class="tm-portfolio-title">My <strong>Past Values</strong></h2>
                    </div>

                    <!-- START ISO SECTION -->
                    <div class="iso-section">
                        <ul class="filter-wrapper clearfix">
                            <li><a href="#" class="opc-main-bg selected" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="opc-main-bg" data-filter=".html">Cat 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="opc-main-bg" data-filter=".photoshop">Cat 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="opc-main-bg" data-filter=".wordpress">Cat 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="opc-main-bg" data-filter=".mobile">Cat 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="iso-box-section">
                            {% for key, value in past_values.items %}
                            <div class="iso-box-wrapper col4-iso-box">
                                <div class="iso-box html photoshop wordpress mobile col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                    <div class="portfolio-thumb">
                                        <img src="{% static 'images/portfolio-img1.jpg' %}" class="fluid-img" alt="portfolio img">
                                        <div class="portfolio-overlay">
                                            <h3 class="portfolio-item-title">{{value}}</h3>
                                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonumm.</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- END PORTFOLIO -->
```

Here is the related CSS:

```
/* START PORTFOLIO */
.tm-portfolio {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
.tm-portfolio .container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.tm-portfolio .col-md-3,
 .tm-portfolio .col-sm-3 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.tm-portfolio-title {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.portfolio-item-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.portfolio-thumb {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.portfolio-overlay {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  background: #eb5424;
  color: #ffffff;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  padding: 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.portfolio-thumb:hover .portfolio-overlay {
  opacity: 0.8;  
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
  transform: scale(1.0);
}
.portfolio-overlay .fa {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #666;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* FILTER CSS */
.filter-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 24px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.filter-wrapper li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
}
.filter-wrapper li a {
  color: #999999;
  padding: 8px 17px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.filter-wrapper li a:focus,
 .filter-wrapper li a:hover,
 .filter-wrapper li a.selected {
  background: #eb5424;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
}

/* ISOTOPE BOX CSS */
.iso-box-section { width: 100%; }
.iso-box-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
}
.iso-box {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.iso-box > a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fluid-img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
/* END PORTFOLIO */
```

For some reason, the final state of my application is this one below. I don't know how to enable the grid when dealing with dynamic content: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cp7D.jpg

The original HTML looks like this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/acwQ7.jpg

I appreciate your help here to understand how Django handles this situation.

Comment: possibly try changing `flex-direction: column;` to `flex-direction: row;` and see if that fixes things

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work. I tried to add an inline CSS and things started to work (The color is just for visual reference):

<div style= "display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; background-color: aqua;" class="iso-section">

The problem is that I have a bunch of space between the fractions that I cannot remove

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgc6I.png

Comment: try using `display: inline-grid;` instead of just grid with your new approach

Comment: it did not work. It's weird. I have never seen something like this happening.